How to change calendar language on TextField type='date'
I am using React and Material-UI
I know about the existence of the LocalizationProvider and how I can use it to change the language of my DatePicker.
However, in my project, I must use TextField with property type= 'date'.
I need this to be able to be dynamically switched between pt-br (Brazilian Portuguese) and en-us (English). (If you guys help me to change it statically I can make it dynamically by myself).
I tried many things but I can't change the language of this calendar (months, abbreviations, etc.).
How can I proceed?
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Date Picker</h1>
            <TextField 
            type='date'
        />
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;

calendar in Portuguese from TextField instead of English
months in Portuguese
I tried to:

inputProps
set locale from my HTML document. language
use the LocalizationProvider with the TextField
Change between Adpterjs and AdapterFns

